# Hyperledger Fabric in Kubernetes: Not able to instantiate chaincode

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

Hello Everyone i am working on setup of  fabric default first-network in kubernetes. But when i am instantiate the chaincode it gives me error. Please check below are my peer logs.

```
  2019-07-22 07:25:02.134 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 066 [mychannel][c4b4e2ae] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed
```

Getting this error on Cli :-

```
 2019-07-22 07:24:58.263 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-07-22 07:24:58.264 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check with my configuration files it was due to wrong CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS  env variable value for the peer.

Answer (score 0):

Once check if all your docker containers are up and running and if you are simply running the sample network without making any changes to the smart contract and the docker files then you can simply stop your network and freshly start the network(it worked in my case).

Comment: I have made some changes issue that i am facing is chaincode instantiate container is not working in kubernetes .